# Compile error Facenet under ncappzoo modules

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, intel

I forgot to mention about my system sorry.

I am using Ubilinux 4 which is based on Debian Stretch. Its kernel is 4.9 LTS. Also my GCC is 7 and Movidius NCSDK is 2.04.00.06. Also I have installed Tensorflow 1.6.

I installed all necessary packages and libraries to compile FaceNet module, but it gives error at every tries.

I have ınstalled NCSDK 2.04.00.06 and tested it, and also compiled some apps/modules like AgeNet and TinyYolo. They are working without problems.

But when I give "make all" under "~/ncappzoo/tensorflow/facenet/", It gives this error:

> making prereqs inception_resnet_v1.py exists, not regetting it.
>
> making zipped model Zipped model already exists, skipping download
>
> making model Zip file exists. Zip file unzipped. mv:
>
> 'model-20170512-110547.ckpt-250000.data-00000-of-00001' durumlanamadı:
>   Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok mv:
>
> 'model-20170512-110547.ckpt-250000.index' durumlanamadı: Böyle bir
>   dosya ya da dizin yok meta file exists Converted directory exists,
>   skipping conversion. #( Here says there is neither a file nor a directory named facenet_celeb_ncs.graph )
>
> ```
> If you want to reconvert remove directory: facenet_celeb_ncs, and re-run
> ```
>
> making compile Command line: mvNCCompile facenet_celeb_ncs.meta -w
>   facenet_celeb_ncs -s 12 -in input -on output -o
>   facenet_celeb_ncs.graph mvNCCompile v02.00, Copyright @ Intel
>   Corporation 2017
>
> Illegal instruction cp: 'facenet_celeb_ncs.graph' durumlanamadı: Böyle
>   bir dosya ya da dizin yok #( Here says there is neither a file nor a  directory named facenet_celeb_ncs.graph )

I haven't tried to upgrade my movidius SDK because I may need update ncappzoo apps that I have modified.

I have problem with just FaceNet module and others works without an issue.

Also, I erased this "20170512-110547" directory and tried "make all" again and same issue still here.

> making prereqs inception_resnet_v1.py exists, not regetting it.
>
> making zipped model Zipped model already exists, skipping download
>
> making model Zip file exists. Unzipping. Archive:  20170512-110547.zip
>
> inflating: 20170512-110547/20170512-110547.pb     inflating:
>
> 20170512-110547/model-20170512-110547.ckpt-250000.data-00000-of-00001
>
> inflating: 20170512-110547/model-20170512-110547.ckpt-250000.index
>
> inflating: 20170512-110547/model-20170512-110547.meta   Converted
>   directory does not exist, doing conversion Illegal instruction
>
> making compile /bin/sh: 7: cd: can't cd to
>   20170512-110547/facenet_celeb_ncs Command line: mvNCCompile
>   facenet_celeb_ncs.meta -w facenet_celeb_ncs -s 12 -in input -on output
>   -o facenet_celeb_ncs.graph mvNCCompile v02.00, Copyright @ Intel Corporation 2017
>
> Illegal instruction cp: 'facenet_celeb_ncs.graph' durumlanamadı: Böyle
>   bir dosya ya da dizin yok #( Here says there is neither a file nor a directory named facenet_celeb_ncs.graph )

How can i solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: What compiler, what version, what OS?  This doesn't look like a [mcve] of the problem you're having.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I have added some information about my system.

Comment: @MustafaSarıalp Instead of editing your question and adding [SOLVED] to the title you must create an answer and mark it as correct, that is the correct way to indicate that a problem was solved in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue. According here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17411#issuecomment-370260582 I should downgrade my Tensorflow package. So after given this command:

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow==1.5.0 --user
```

my issue solved. Thank you.